# Sticky footer margin issue

Tags: html, css

I am playing around with [CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)  and I have an issue where...

```
* { margin: 0; }
```

Although it is designed to reset all DIV margins, this is not what I want to do. The text on every page are squished and have no margins now.

I have tried defining it on every element I want but with no success i.e...

```
div.wrapper, div.push, div.footer { margin: 0; }
```

How can I bypass it so only the necessary elements by sticky footer have a margin of 0, and the rest remain untouched?

Comment: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: A bad solution would be to use *:not(p)

Comment: Replace the margins in your `p` with padding.

Comment: "Although it is designed to reset all DIV margins, this is not what I want to do" What *do* you want it to do?

Comment: Also, sorry, it's all text, not just p tags, my bad. Updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the * CSS and change the HTML one to:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.footer * {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It fixes all the text, but it doesn't fix the Sticky footer. The text inside the footer looks like it's triple spaced or something.

Comment: see my edit ifwhen it becomes live. `.footer * {
    margin: 0;
}`

Comment: That works rather well, thank you :) One thing is though, the .container inside .footer has width: 1025px and margin: 0 auto; to center the .container. With the code above, it is pushed to the left. How can I fix this?

Comment: Usually the parent DIV should have width 100% cant see that in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it.. why use sticky footer. Try creating a css table structure like this. People underestimate CSS tables! They can be awesome in creating fluid designs..

```
#wrapper { display: table; height: 100%; width: 1000px; }
#wrapper > header, #wrapper > footer { display: table-row; min-height: 100px; }
#main { height: 100%; } 

<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>I'm a header!</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="main">

  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>I'm a footer!</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

In this CSS example none of the other elements will be affected and both the footer and header keep their height while the mid section is fluid filling the restspace..

Also take a look at table-cell.. it allowes for horizontal structurs like a solid left side with a fluid main section.

Answer (score 0):

Also to correct the text in the fotter you can edit this CSS:

```
font: 0.8em helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
```

Line 50 of the style.css

```
.footer p {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 4px;
width: 700px;
padding: 0;
color: white;
font: 0.8em helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a premade sticky footer if it's been created that easily?
Try:

```
<footer><span>Footer Content</span></footer>
```

with the following CSS:

```
footer{    
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:30px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    color: #595959;
    font-size: 9pt;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: The fixed footer can be a pain in the ass when the website exceeds the browsers max height. It is also not recommended for mobile devices using a small screen.